# Enclose code in anonymous brackets saves memory?

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm a beginner and for some reason, I like to make effort to save memory. For now I think it's fun.

So in this problem, I have a regex that matches kebab-case words and later turns them into camel-case words, and I want to know if that is some occurrence in a given string. I tried `Matcher.matches()` but I found out that it only works if the entire string is matched, so I only could think of compiling the regex and use the `Matcher.find()` method to put a boolean value inside a variable, but I wanted to enclose everything in brackets to save memory.

This is my solution:

```java
String regex = "(?:([\\p{IsAlphabetic}]*)?(-[\\p{IsAlphabetic}]+))+";

boolean hasSubSequence;
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(identifier);
    hasSubSequence = m.find();
}

if (hasSubSequence) {
    Matcher kebabCaseMatches = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(identifier);
    while (kebabCaseMatches.find()) {
        String currentOccurence = kebabCaseMatches.group();
        
        while (currentOccurence.contains("-")) {
            currentOccurence = currentOccurence.replaceFirst("-[\\p{IsAlphabetic}]", Character.toString(Character.toUpperCase(currentOccurence.charAt(currentOccurence.indexOf("-") + 1))));
        }
        
        // "identifier" is the function's argument
        identifier = identifier.replaceFirst(regex, currentOccurence);
    }
}
```

Does this really save memory?

Comment: Probably not.  It certainly won't cause the matcher instance to be reclaimed significantly earlier.  It might conceivably save one reference variable in the stack frame of the enclosing method.  But unless this is being used recursively that will be irrelevant.

Comment: This question *smells* of [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: @StephenC That article changed my mind! It could be a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compile the pattern once where you declared `regex` (static final?): would save speed and many instances. Brackets are voodoo.